# running an ant build file on remote system

Tags: java, ant, build-process, build-automation

I have an build file located on a remote system. I want to run it there itself.It would be good if I can invoke it using a java program from my local system only.I tried using google but no success.Is it possible at all?

Comment: Perhaps you should look into CI systems, such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: how do you connect to your remote system? PuTTy, telnet etc.??? What tool do you use?

Comment: wouldnt you do a remote login with something like SSH and invoke the script there?

Comment: Yes ofcourese we do have telnet,putty and ssh login but credentials are not shared among every body.I would like to develope a web portal to run different build files on different environments.

Comment: Whatever you use to do the remote login may be invokable from java. There you could add a script to run the build file.

Comment: Batch files or shell script kept in every environment, triggered from a web based front end might do the trick for you. And, as suggested by @AndersR.Bystrup, you should definitely look into Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

(extending comments on jenkins into answer)

I suggest Jenkins with master slave configuration to fully automate your build process. It comes with hundreds of plugin (You have plugins for static code analsys, test, test report, publishing , deployment.., supports many VCS).

Jenkins exposes operations via web-gui. It also has [command line tool to aid in automation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) .  You can easily add multiple machines into build and extend your workflow..

If your slaves are on windows, only trouble you have is an FAQ: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM